# Connectivity issue between Windows 10 (on-premises) and Windows Server 2016 on Azure

Tags: azure, windows-server, domaincontroller

Using Point-to-Site connection, I planned to connect Windows 10 (on-premises) and Windows Server 2016 on Azure so that Windows 10 (on-premises) can join Windows Server 2016 Domain Controller.

I am trying to elaborate steps that I followed:

Step1: Create a **Resource Group**, say *SkyTech* with the **Region** *East US*.

a). Create an **Availability Set**, say *1ASet.SkyTech* with details as

**Resource Group**: *SkyTech*

**Region**: *East US*

**Fault domains**: *2* (default)

**Update domains**: *5* (default)

**Use managed disks**: *Yes(Aligned)* (default)

b). Create a **Virtual network**, say, *1VNet.East* with details as

**Address space**: *15.0.0.0/25*

**Resource Group**: *SkyTech*

**Location**: *East US*

**Subnet**: *1SubNet.East*

**Address range**: *15.0.0.0/26*

**DDoS Protection**: *Basic* (default)

**Service endpoints**: *Disabled* (default)

**Firewall**: *Disabled* (default)

c). Create **Gateway subnet** for the virtual network *1VNet.East* with details as

**Address range**: *15.0.0.128/28* (selected automatically)

**Network security group**: *None* (default)

**Route table**: *None* (default)

**Service endpoints**: *0 selected* (default)

**Subnet delegation**: *None* (default)

Step2: Create **virtual network gateway** with details as

**Name**: *SkyTech.EastUS*

**Region**: *East US*

**Gateway type**: *VPN*

**VPN type**: *Route-based*

**SKU**: *Basic*

**Virtual network**: *1VNet.East*

**Gateway subnet address range**: *15.0.0.128/28* (selected automatically)

**Public IP address**: *Create new*

**Public IP address**: *SkyTech.Pub.IP*

**Public IP address SKU**: *Basic* (selected automatically)

**Assignment**: *Dynamic* (selected automatically)

**Enable active-active mode**: *Disabled* (default)

**Configure BGP ASN**: *Disabled* (default)

Step3: Generate and export certificates of the Windows 10 (on premises) computer.

a). Create a self-signed root certificate

b). Generate a client certificate

Step4: Export the root certificate public key (.cer)

Step5: Export the self-signed root certificate and private key to store it

Step6: Configure **Point-to-Site Configuration** in the Virtual Network Gateway

Added **Address Pool** like *172.16.25.0/24*

Added **Root Certificates** and **Public Certification Data** of the desktop computer (on the premises).

Clicked **Save** and then **Download VPN client**.

Step7: Installed **VPN client** in the desktop computer (on premises)

Connected **VPN**.

In the **ipconfig**, the desktop computer is showing the address from the **Address Pool** (172.16.25.0/24) under PPP Adaptor.

Steps8: Create virtual machine

**Resource group**: *SkyTech*

**Virtual machine name**: *SkyTech.EastUS*

**Region**: *East US*

**Availability option**: *Availability set*

**Availability set**: *1ASet.SkyTech*

**Image**: *Windows Server 2016 Datacentre*

**Authentication type**: *Password*

**Username**: *Admin.SkyTech*

**Password**: *Admin@123*

**Confirm password**: *Admin@123*

**Public inbound ports**: Allow selected ports

**Select inbound ports**: *RDP*

**Already have a Windows Server license**: *No*

**Disk options (OS disk type)**: *Premium SSD*

**Virtual network**: *1VNet.East*

**Subnet**: *1SubNet.East*

**NIC network security group**: *Basic*

**Accelerated networking**: *Off*

**Place this virtual machine behind an existing load balancing solution**: *No*

**Boot diagnostic**: *Off*

**OS guest diagnostics**: *Off*

**System assigned managed identity**: *Off*

**Enable auto-shutdown**: *Off*

**Enable backup**: *Off*

Step9: Static IP the virtual machine

In virtual machine, **Settings > Networking**

There are **NIC Public IP**: 40.82.x.x and **NIC Private IP**: 15.0.0.4

Click **40.82.x.x > Settings > Configuration**

**Assignment**: *Static*

Then, **Save**

Steps10: Created DNS Server at the VNet level as follows:
[image]
Used 15.0.0.4 as a Private IP in **Custom**.

**I tried all above steps about times in the order of Step1 to Step10.**

**The issue is:**

From Windows 10 (on-premises) computer, I am able to connect Windows Server 2016 VM *SkyTech.EastUS* using RDP with Public IP and with Private IP both.

But both (Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016) are not pinging each other so that I can join Windows 10 to Windows Server 2016 Domain Controller.

Moreover, after all Steps (From Step1 to Step10), I added role of Active Directory Domain Services and promoted Windows Server 2016 as a Domain Controller.

Then, I tried to join Windows 10 to Windows Server 2016 Domain Controller. I see error message as follows:

[image]

Please let me know, what I need and where I am wrong.

Regards

TekQ

Answer (score 0):

you need your vm to be able to talk to the domain controller and you vm to be able to resolve the dns name of your domain to one of the domain controllers. Usually you just specify on or more of your domain controllers as dns servers for the vm.

Alternatively you can set them at VNet level, so the settings are applied to all the VMs in the Vnet.

For connectivity you can use Vnet peering or Site-to-Site VPN.

Comment: said about using Vnet peering or Site-to-Site VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Two points you have to do:

- Deploy a DNS server. Usually, you could do this via adding a DNS role in the DC VM or another server in the same VNet. Specify the DNS server private IP address in the [DNS servers of Azure VNet](http://dataap.org/blog/2017/05/05/connect-azure-virtual-machines-on-a-same-domain/) on the Azure portal.
- Create a [Azure VPN gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways) to connect between the on-premise network and Azure VNet. In this case, for one or fewer clients, you could use a P2S VPN gateway. For a corp, you could use the S2S VPN gateway. This way needs a VPN device.

Once the VPN gateway set up and you can ping the Azure VM via private IP address, then you could join the desktop to the ADDC domain. Note, once you update the DNS or other settings in the Azure VNet, you have to re-download the VPN client to make the local DNS or route update if you have a P2S gateway.

Comment: thank you for your effort. The link http://dataap.org/blog/2017/05/05/connect-azure-virtual-machines-on-a-same-domain/ says about adding the domain control IP address at Network Interface of DNS Server on Azure Portal. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways says about virtual network gateway.

Comment: Theoretically I know Windows Server 2016 VM and Windows 10 Pro desktop must be able to ping each other and after then Window 10 Pro can join Windows Server 2016 VM.

Comment: Theoretically Its okay but I am unable to understand how to start it practically. The Public IP of Windows Server 2016 is 104.x.x.x, Private IP is 10.x.x.x and the IP assigned on Windows 10 Pro desktop computer is 192.168.x.x. Please guide me what & how I need to setup practically.

Comment: Check another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167112/is-it-possible-to-join-a-local-windows-machine-on-premises-to-a-windows-server) for details. and [P2S VPN configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal).

Comment: I have gone through the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal. While creating a virtual network gateway, Public IP Address is required. The link says, specify the public IP address object that gets associated to the VPN gateway. How do I know, what public IP address will get associated to the VPN Gateway?

Comment: Just click create a new public IP when you deploy the VPN gateway on the Azure portal, just need following that link, Azure will dynamically assign a PIP for your VPN gateway.

Comment: I uploaded an image. Pls look and guide me which type of public IP address should I use? Can I use any random public IP address or any criteria?

Comment: It's just a name for a public IP address, you can use any string between 1-80 characters. For example, give a name `vm-pip`, It will show the name when you find the IP resources in your resource group after created the VPN.

Comment: Sorry for delay in response. I have gone through steps explained in various links but the issue is not resolved.

Comment: I can do it via the steps, maybe you can contact MS support for direct support. It's difficult to help you on the forum with few information on your side.

Comment: Let me know, what other information is required from my side? I'll try to provide more information.

Comment: Do you specify the DNS server private IP address in the `DNS servers` of Azure VNet on the Azure portal refer to [this](http://dataap.org/blog/2017/05/05/connect-azure-virtual-machines-on-a-same-domain/)? If the network connectivity is well, consider if the on-premise client could lookup the DC via DNS, you should have a DNS server role on the Azure VM in the Azure vnet.

Comment: I edited my question for elaborating steps I followed. Pls guide me accordingly.

Comment: Please hide your admin or password info or other sensitive data. Do you join the VM via UI? Is there any error message when you join the domain? When a VPN connection is connected, can you see the DNS server is15.0.0.4 in `ipconfig/all` on the VPN client? If you set up DC and DNS role on Azure VM, you can refer to [this1](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/create-vms-to-run-domain-controller-and-dns-server-roles/), if you join an Azure VM to an on-prem Active Directory. You can refer to [this2](https://4sysops.com/archives/join-an-azure-vm-to-an-on-prem-active-directory/).

Comment: I know admin and password are sensitive date. Both are just for an example. I paraphrased step 10 and edited my question with error message. I checked at VPN client only by ipconfig. In the ipconfig, the VPN client is showing the address from the Address Pool (172.16.25.0/24) under PPP Adaptor. Once again, I do the setup and check ipconfig/all. Pls let me know, what I need to check more.

Comment: Do you see the dns server IP under PPP Adaptor when `ipconfig/all`? And what's your DNS server, you should have a DNS role in this DC machine or other VM on the same Vnet. Is there an `A` record in the DNS zone `skytechdc.com`? Also you can check the details in that error message.